# I need help reading Xcode's error console

Tags: swift, xcode, sigabrt

I'm an Xcode beginner and am having trouble reading the error console to fix whatever has been making my app crash.  My code (Swift) compiles, but I get the SIGABRT error that I've seen so many other threads about. It seems like the solution is pretty different for each problem.

```
2017-05-08 20:57:32.821 ChordGenerator[6335:422217] -[ChordGenerator.ViewController newChordButton:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9ec6407fd0
2017-05-08 20:57:32.825 ChordGenerator[6335:422217] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ChordGenerator.ViewController newChordButton:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9ec6407fd0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b0beb0b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010828b141 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b12e134 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b045840 ___forwarding___ + 1024
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b0453b8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   UIKit                               0x0000000108f87d22 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83
    6   UIKit                               0x000000010910c25c -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010910c577 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 450
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010910b4b2 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 618
    9   UIKit                               0x0000000108ff549a -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 2707
    10  UIKit                               0x0000000108ff6bb0 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 4114
    11  UIKit                               0x0000000108fa37b0 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 352
    12  UIKit                               0x0000000109786adc __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 2926
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010977ea3a __handleEventQueue + 1122
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b064c01 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b04a0cf __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 527
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b0495ff __CFRunLoopRun + 911
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b049016 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 406
    18  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010cf7ba24 GSEventRunModal + 62
    19  UIKit                               0x0000000108f860d4 UIApplicationMain + 159
    20  ChordGenerator                      0x0000000107cb06a7 main + 55
    21  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010c01065d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: `SIGABRT` only means that it is a `SIG`nal for the process to `AB`o`RT`. Look at the first two lines of the error, maybe that will give some hints to the source of the error?

Comment: Here is the issue `reason: '-[ChordGenerator.ViewController newChordButton:]:`. Either the method `newChordButton` doesn't exist or the class doesn't conform to this method.

Comment: Fix your button action so it points to a valid method in your view controller.

Answer (score 1):

`2017-05-08 20:57:32.821 ChordGenerator[6335:422217] -[ChordGenerator.ViewController newChordButton:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9ec6407fd0`

This is the line you need to focus on. According to this, your project "ChordGenerator" which has a file "ViewController" has some function to which you are passing a selector "newChordButton". Currently, the system is unable to find that function. All in all, pass a function **name** that exists in the scope of the target i.e. if target=self, then the function newChordButton must be there in the current ViewController.swift class.

If you are testing, simply make an empty function:

`func newChordButton(){
  print("Entered newChordButton function")
}`